# Force Modal MS-Access Form to show as tab

Tags: ms-access

My Access 2019 database shows all forms as tabs.
Except when I open a modal form.  It appears in a window.
How do I get modal forms to appear as a tab every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Modal and popup forms are floating windows.

However, you can under Options uncheck "Show document tabs", and the normal forms will have no tab tabs displayed, though that may have some downsides when navigating your application.